# Access methods not exposed in the method mapping table with ctypes

Tags: python, c, garbage-collection, ctypes

The method mapping table is an array of PyMethodDef structures,

```
struct PyMethodDef {
   char *ml_name;
   PyCFunction ml_meth;
   int ml_flags;
   char *ml_doc;
};
```

where the **ml_name** is the name of the functions accessed in the interpreter (i.e. gc.collect()), **ml_meth** is the address of the function described in the previous section, **ml_flags** indicates which of the signatures ml_meth is using and **ml_doc** is the docstring for the function.

Now, say I want to access from within the gcmodule.c gc_list_append which is not exposed by the gc interface.

I've tried the following:

```
pythonapi.PyImport_ImportModule("gcmodule")
```

or

```
pythonapi.PyImport_ImportModule(ctypes.c_wchar("gcmodule"))
```

Hoping that the reference returned can be used to access unexposed methods, but in both cases I get errors:

```
ImportError: No module named 'g'
```

or

```
TypeError: one character unicode string expected
```

Any idea how an unexposed function or data structures can be accessed via ctypes/pythonapi?

Comment: Maybe `gc_list_append` is a random example, but that hasn't been used since at least 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PyImport_ImportModule`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/import.html#PyImport_ImportModule) imports a module as named by the `const char *` argument. It calls `PyImport_Import`, which in turn calls `__builtin__.__import__` in PY2. Calling it with the C string `"gc"` returns a reference to `sys.modules['gc']` if it exists, else the interpreter creates the module by calling [`initgc`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/gcmodule.c#l1385) , which it finds in [`_PyImport_Inittab`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/config.c.in#l33). The gc module's init function calls [`Py_InitModule4`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/allocation.html#Py_InitModule4), which loops over the `GcMethods` table to add methods to the module dict.

Every global definition you see in gcmodule.c that's marked `static` is only visible within that compilation unit at the system level, i.e. it doesn't have external linkage. Commonly an extension module only exports the name of the `PyMODINIT_FUNC`, but several of the built-in modules in CPython also export public APIs such as `PyObject_GC_Track`.

On Windows, exporting a symbol from a DLL by name or ordinal requires the extra step of declaring it in a .def file or with the modifier `__declspec(dllexport)`. In CPython that gets applied via the macros [`PyAPI_FUNC`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Include/pyport.h#l735) (pyport.h), `PyAPI_DATA`, and `PyMODINIT_FUNC`. For example, objimpl.h declares `PyAPI_FUNC(void) PyObject_GC_Track(void *)`.

Declaring a symbol `static` is namespace management. However, if you can get the address of a function somehow, you can certainly call it with a ctypes function pointer. Finding the address is the issue. ctypes uses the standard POSIX [`dlsym`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) and Windows [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions to look up exported symbols, which won't help you here. You may be able to access function pointers referenced directly or indirectly by CPython objects, since `id` returns the object base address.

---

The following isn't directly related to your problem, but I'm including it for general interest.

On a POSIX system that loads extension modules with `dlopen`, you can specify `RTLD_GLOBAL` to merge the dynamic symbols into the global namespace. For example, the `_ctypes` extension module is linked from multiple object files and needs several `extern` symbols, such as `PyCData_set`. You can tweak the import to have `PyCData_set` accessible globally (e.g. via `ctypes.pythonapi`):

```
>>> import sys, DLFCN
>>> sys.setdlopenflags(DLFCN.RTLD_GLOBAL | DLFCN.RTLD_NOW)
>>> import ctypes
>>> hasattr(ctypes.pythonapi, 'PyCData_set')
True
```

Of course, that won't work on Windows. The proper way for an extension module to make a C API available is by using a [`PyCapsule`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/capsule.html), such as [`datetime.datetime_CAPI`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/datetimemodule.c#l4746) (datetimemodule.c).

Comment: So there's no way to access them via ctypes or any other related module in Python?